# custom media player error on Android 2.3

Tags: android, media-player

I tried to make android custom videoplayer, and its working fine then i play music. 
But i got error (1,-38) on 2.3 then trying display video on surface.

```
 // Mediaplayer
   mp = new MediaPlayer();
   mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() 
   {
           public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
           {    
              isPrepared = true;
              mp.start();
            }
    });

   mp.setDataSource("http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp");
   mp.prepareAsync();
   mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mp.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);//if comment this string - player is working fine
```

How to fix it?

**What is difference between android 2.3 and 4.0 mediaplayer?**

Comment: `-38` is `INVALID_OPERATION` (typically that you called one of the `MediaPlayer` methods while in an incorrect state). It would be good to know which call generated the error. What else does logcat say?

Comment: Nothing, only this error.

Comment: Since `setDisplay()` can be called in any state, there's a good chance your `surfaceHolder` variable is not set up correctly. It'd be good to show the code related to that too. Also, according to the docs you should call `setAudioStreamType(...)` before preparing the player in order to take effect.

Comment: surfaceHolder is initialized in onCreate, before init player.

Comment: Have you solved this @Sergey? I have the same problem and kind of feel this got in the "Wisdom of the anceints" state.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it :

> ```
>       mp.setDataSource(url); 
>       mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
>       mp.prepareAsync();
>     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
>       mp.start();
>     }
> ```

**EDIT :**

I think you should set an error listener using setOnErrorListener to see if you get any error when calling setDataSource.

Answer (score 0):

Mine issue turned to be that I provided wrong url for the video playback. I had two urls -one for the raw data and one for progress streaming-comapatible format. I had supplied the first one by mistake. Swapping them fixed my issue. Older Android versions have poorer support for HLS video streaming (that's why the differnce on the different Android versions):

- Android 2.3 (Gingerbread)

  - No Support, despite being the most popular version of Android
- Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)

  - Streams cause tablet devices to crash
- Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)

  - VOD streams do not seek
  - Aspect ratios are not detected and cause image deformation
  - Fullscreen causes videos to restart from the beginning
- Android 4.1+ (Jelly Bean)

  - Aspect ratio issue is fixed, but seek is still unavailable
  - Chrome does not understand HLS leading to broken mimetype detection
  - Taking video fullscreen causes devices to throw an error and stop.

This data is taken from [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/).

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem of MediaPlayer error (1,-38) after calling mediaPlayer.start() on Android 2.3 device, just add the following clause after setting up the surface holder.

`...;
    surfaceHolder_.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder_.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mediaPlayer_ = new MediaPlayer();
    ...;`

For devices equal to or higher than Honeycomb, we don't need to set the surface holder type, the framework will handle that automatically for the attached surface view to the media player, that's why the code works in Android 4.0 but not in 2.3.